# Django project template doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

Hi i'm just getting started with Django and i'm running a project, I have created an HTML file and this is the views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "hello/index.html")
```

and this is the urls.py inside the maine file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))
]
```

and this is the urls.py inside the project file

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
   
]
```

and i got this error [image]

view from my project
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. You have written `templetes` instead of `templates`

Comment: Those dang "pletes". Gets me every time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure You have template folder same as where your manage.py
and also in settings.py

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Comment: I'm following this lecture https://youtu.be/w8q0C-C1js4 and i got stuck at minute 29 when he changed HttpResponse to render and added the html file. it didn't work for me

Comment: change the template folder bro you named it wrong (check spellings).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have simply misspelt the the template folder as `templetes` within your hello app. Rename it as **templates** and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your main `settings.py` file.
and replace `YOUR_APP_NAME` with your django app name

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'YOUR_APP_NAME/templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating the folder named templates inside the hello app. Then create a folder named by the app name 'hello'. That will enable django to read inside that folder and fetch for the template named index.html.

And the path will look like
`projectDir/hello/templates/hello/index.html`

Do so, hope it will help.